# Ember action target to specific component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've recently upgrade to ember version 1.13.5

How can I target an action to an specific component, it was working on previous version and now it doesn't respond

```
<a href="#" class="nav-action" {{action 'open' target='view.appOverlay.categorySideMenu'}}><i class="fi-list"></i></a>
```

In other part of the template I have this

```
{{#overlay-fx viewName="appOverlay" open="openSideMenu"}}
    {{#side-menu  open="open" use="toRight" targetObject=view.appOverlay viewName="userSideMenu"}}
        {{partial "partial/user-side-menu"}}
    {{/side-menu}}
    {{#side-menu  open="open" use="toLeft" targetObject=view.appOverlay viewName="categorySideMenu"}}
        {{partial "partial/category-side-menu"}}
    {{/side-menu}}
{{/overlay-fx}}
```

Is it because of view deprecations, now you can't event access components with view.NAME ?

I just keep getting this error, which is common if action doesn't bubble

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'open'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
```

Comment: this would appear to be a true breaking change. Any chance you could create a JSBin or at the very least open a legit issue on github about this? I don't think the core team intended a simple upgrade to break anything. Just curious -what version of ember did you upgrade from (when this was working) ?

Comment: Looks like you indeed found a regression, I've put your question in the ember-dev Slack channel. Could you try replacing `view.appOverlay` with `view.childViews.appOverlay`?

Comment: I try changing to view.childViews, but still same error, I'm going to replicate in jsbin for better debugging... tnx guys

Answer (score 0):

Well after several try an errors, the solution was to remove the "'s from the target parameter on action

It end up like this

```
<a href="#" class="nav-action" {{action 'open' target=view.appOverlay.categorySideMenu}}><i class="fi-list"></i></a>
```

Seems to be silly, but its not documented anywhere, maybe new changes propagate to all views that receives functions, lost hours debugging this.